# How to cache aggregate column values on Doctrine_Record instance?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

Lets say i have a record class that often gets queried with dyanmic colums that are MySQL aggregate values:

```
$results = Doctrine_Core::getTable('MyRecord')->creatQuery('m')
  ->select('m.*, AVG(m.rating) as avg_rating, SUM(m.id) as nb_related') 
  ->innerJoin('m.AnotherRecords a')
  ->where('m.id = ?')
  ->fetchOne();
```

Now lets say i want a method on that record to check if the aggregate columns exist from when the record was queried, and if not then i  want to go ahead an issue a separate query to get these values:

```
// this doesnt actually work because of filterSet and filterGet
// but its general idea
public function getAverageRating($wtihNbRelated = false)
{
  if(!isset($this->avg_rating) || ($withNbRelated && !isset($this->nb_related))
  {
     $rating = $this->getTable()->getAverageRating($this, $withNbRelated);
     $this->avg_rating = $rating['avg_rating'];

     if($withNbRealted)
     {
       $this->nb_related = $rating['nb_related'];
     }
  }

  return $withNbRelated
    ? array('avg_rating' => $this->avg_rating, 'nb_related' => $this->nb_related)
    : array('avg_rating' => $this->avg_rating);
}
```

Is there an easy way (ie. not writing a custom hydrator) to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer really. I forgot that Doctrine prefixes all its direct protected members with `_`. So, even though i initially tried manipulating the `data` member i was forgot the prefix giving me the same result as if i tried `$this->avg_rating` or its accessor method. The solution was:

```
public function getAverageRating($wtihNbRelated = false)
{
  if(!isset($this->_data['avg_rating']) || ($withNbRelated && !isset($this->_data['nb_related']))
  {
     $rating = $this->getTable()->getAverageRating($this, $withNbRelated);
     $this->_data['avg_rating'] = $rating['avg_rating'];

     if($withNbRealted)
     {
       $this->_data['nb_related'] = $rating['nb_related'];
     }
  }

  return $withNbRelated
    ? array('avg_rating' => $this->_data['avg_rating'], 'nb_related' => $this->_data['nb_related'])
    : array('avg_rating' => $this->_data['avg_rating']);
}
```